# Doubt on genomic code for nucleosome positioning?

Tags: genetics, epigenetics

I was reading "[A genomic code for nucleosome positioning](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~/eran/NucleosomeModel.pdf)" (by Eran Segal et al). And I am having 2 doubts.
[image]

The figure(b) in this image from the paper shows the graph of fraction (3-bp moving average) of AA/TA/TT dinucleotides of nucleosome dna sequence they analysed statistically as far as I understand.
What is 3-bp moving average here?
I also don't understand how they chose 0th position (the so called dyad). 
Also what does it mean to have oscillations (correlation?) in this graph?

---

UPDATE : I am adding some supplementary information related to finding the dinucleotide fractions. Still I don't understand why is the fraction found so?

[image]

Comment: Your image is a little blurry. Can you upload a higher resolution image?

Comment: @WYSIWYG : done

Comment: Okay I edited the answer. Let me know if that is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dyad is the centre of the DNA that is wrapped around the nucleosome core (It basically is the centre of symmetry of the nucleosome). It is a common practice to set it at 0 thereby making incoming DNA half, negative and outgoing DNA half, positive.

By oscillations the authors mean that there is a periodic repeat of A/T dinucleotide. IMO it is actually not correct to call it oscillation which is mostly used in a time course dynamical sense.

I guess this is what is meant by the **3-nt moving average**:

You have conditional dinucleotide probabilities for each position (As shown in the figure). Now you calculate the A/T dinucleotide probability which is:

```
 P[A/T] = PAA + PAT + PTT + PTA
```

Now you find the moving average for 3 steps:

```
MA(n) = (1/3)×(P[A/T](n) + P[A/T](n-1) + P[A/T](n-2))

where n is the nth position of the DNA
```

Comment: The term "oscillations" is my word, not authors'.

Comment: I did not understood the 3-bp moving average filter argument, but now I have access to ~70 page supplementary data of the paper. I am updating my question.

Comment: In the graph (b) of first image but "AT" is not mentioned? only AA/TA/TT is mentioned.

Comment: @dexterdev I think `TA` and `AT` are grouped together as `TA` (combination of `T` and `A`); there is no rationale for not including `AT`.

Comment: `AT` and `TA` in this paper are different. `AT` is `T` after `A` and `TA` is `A` after `T`. The supplementary data shows a different separate plot for this. Should I update the question with those plots. I am still in confusion?

Comment: @dexterdev Unless I read the entire paper I wont know what they have done. I know that `AT` is different from `TA` but all I am saying is that when `TA` is counted then it makes no sense to exclude `AT`. You need not modify your question because this doubt is just about what have they counted and for that you just need to look at the paper. The answer will still remain the same.

Comment: Any way thanks for the effort, but they are counting both the AT and TA differently.

Comment: @dexterdev they must have mentioned why they are doing so. You just need to read the paper carefully. You must exempt me from that effort :)

Comment: I agree to that. :)